# Force child element width not to overflow within flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there any way in restricting the "a" element width within the container div in this example so it nevers overflows on its right, so it breaks any caracter making a new line ?

Thanks

```css
body{background:#FFF;}
img{width:80px;}
.container{
 border:1px dashed #F00;
 width:120px;
 display:flex;flex-direction:row;
 /*align-self: flex-end;*/
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
a{display:inline-block;border:1px dashed #00C;margin:auto;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap: break-word;}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="container">
   <img class=picto src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png'/>
   <a class="input">testtxtis longone</a> 
 </div> 
Shall be contained in container not overflow
</body>
```

Comment: `min-width:0` to a